# How IDA will load DLL at constant memory segment at debug process?

Tags: python, debugging, reverse-engineering, ida

Each time TEST_DEBUG.EXE loaded at 0x04000000 base in IDA-Modules, but
TEST_DEBUG.DLL file loaded at  any randoms base like 0x0C120000,  0x0C710000  , 0x0ABC0000 
How i say to IDA debugger, load TEST_DEBUG.DLL every time at 0x0ABC0000 BASE ?

PS:
TEST_DEBUG.EXE  load many DLLS, and one of them is TEST_DEBUG.DLL

Answer (score 0):

NO ONE KNOW ?
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\x86_arm>EDITBIN /REBASE:BASE=0x61000000 mydll.dll